# mod rewrite to match number at end of string

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a bit mod rewrite regex and getting stuck.

I want to parse the following url structure to give variables to my script:

```
dogs/staffordshire-brown-hampshire-32
```

(32 is the variable I want to pass)..

```
index.php?type=dogs&id=$matches[1]
```

I have this so far which doesn't seem to work

```
dogs/([^-]*$)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will match the entire string after dogs if it doesn't contain a hyphen.  Try:

```
dogs/.*?([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: Hi, that gives me the last digit, i.e. in the example above - 2.

Comment: @Will, try adding a `?` after `.*`

Comment: I think that just got quickly edited! Unless I'm losing it. Anyway thanks to both, works like a charm.

Comment: @Will, true, I edited it in :). I didn't want to create a whole new answer where mine was about the same as Bill's but with a `?` after `.*`. Be sure to click the "accepted" mark next to Bill's answer.